# R transform column with string as character, not as factor

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

I am curious about the behaviour of `transform`. Two ways I might try creating a new column as character not as factor:

```
x <- data.frame(Letters = LETTERS[1:3], Numbers = 1:3)
y <- transform(x, Alphanumeric = as.character(paste(Letters, Numbers)))
x$Alphanumeric = with(x, as.character(paste(Letters, Numbers)))
x
y
str(x$Alphanumeric)
str(y$Alphanumeric)
```

The results "look" the same:

```
> x
  Letters Numbers Alphanumeric
1       A       1          A 1
2       B       2          B 2
3       C       3          C 3
> y
  Letters Numbers Alphanumeric
1       A       1          A 1
2       B       2          B 2
3       C       3          C 3
```

But look inside and only one has worked:

```
> str(x$Alphanumeric) # did convert to character
 chr [1:3] "A 1" "B 2" "C 3"
> str(y$Alphanumeric) # but transform didn't
 Factor w/ 3 levels "A 1","B 2","C 3": 1 2 3
```

I didn't find `?transform` very useful to explain this behaviour - presumably `Alphanumeric` was coerced back to being a factor - or find a way to stop it (something like `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` for `data.frame`). What is the safest way to do this? Are there similar pitfalls to beware of, for instance with the `apply` or `plyr` functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not so much an issue with `transform` as much as it is with `data.frame`s, where `stringsAsFactors` is set, by default, to `TRUE`. Add an argument that it should be `FALSE` and you'll be on your way:

```
y <- transform(x, Alphanumeric = paste(Letters, Numbers),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(y)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Letters     : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
#  $ Numbers     : int  1 2 3
#  $ Alphanumeric: chr  "A 1" "B 2" "C 3"
```

I generally use `within` instead of `transform`, and it seems to not have this problem:

```
y <- within(x, {
  Alphanumeric = paste(Letters, Numbers)
})
str(y)
# 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Letters     : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
#  $ Numbers     : int  1 2 3
#  $ Alphanumeric: chr  "A 1" "B 2" "C 3"
```

This is because it takes an approach similar to your `with` approach: Create a character vector and add it (via `[<-`) into the existing `data.frame`.

You can view the source of each of these by typing `transform.data.frame` and `within.data.frame` at the prompt.

---

As for other pitfalls, that's much too broad of a question. One thing that comes to mind right waya is that `apply` would create a `matrix` from a `data.frame`, so all the columns would be coerced to a single type.

Comment: Thanks! I wondered about `stringsAsFactors` but couldn't see what it would actually get passed to - I'd assumed it had to be inside `data.frame`. Could you explain what's going on?

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm so used to `x$char <- as.character(...)` I just expect it to work, but now I wonder why it doesn't get coerced analogously...

Comment: @Silverfish, what you're doing with `transform` is more like `y <- cbind(x, A = paste(x$Letters, x$Numbers))` than using `[<-` as you describe.

Comment: That makes sense. I notice that `y <- cbind(x, A = paste(x$Letters, x$Numbers), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` also prevents coercion to factor. I still wonder where the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is getting passed to?

Comment: It gets passed to `data.frame`

Comment: Ah right, inside `transform.data.frame`. That's very helpful.